# Path to pictures in Joomla site changed to ajax path

Tags: joomla-4.x, ajax, images

I created a website with Joomla and YooTheme. All of a sudden, none of the pictures show anymore. What used to be path [domainname]/images/[imagename].jpg is now [domainname]/de/component/ajax/?p=image&src=[imagename].jpg. The site is http://joo.sprachgefuehl.ch/. I don't know what caused joomla to try to load images through ajax and how to fix it to have images display again. Does anyone have any suggestions how to resolve this?

Comment: We are probably going to need more debugging details.  Do you have your error reporting turned all of the way up?  Are there any errors in your error logs? Do the sought files still exist in the directory where you expect to find them?

Comment: Are your images in the /images/ folder? Are your images visible in the Joomla back-end? And in the YOOtheme Pro back-end? Can you open the images directly in your browser when you add the path in the URL?

Comment: @mickmackusa: I turned on the debugging, Logging is set to log almost everything. There are no error messages in the logs. The image files are still in the /images directory. The images are not visible in the back end, because the backend tries to display the images with the same ajax path as the front end. There is no error in the terminal. If I put in the address of an image in the url, I get a HTTP 200 response, but the picture is not visible.